# Top Microphone & Bottom Microphone on android how to select?

Tags: android, audio

I am building my Apps that can record audio. But I wonder how to select top or bottom microphone on my device. 
I read documents on https://developer.android.com/ and I know that We can use **MediaRecorder class** to record audio, it has 2 define MIC and CAMCORDER.
If we use MIC define then phone will use bottom Microphone
else we use CAMCORDER then phone will use top Microphone. Is that right?

```
            mFileName = FunctionIndex.PATH + "/" + this.functionKey +".3gp";
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                MyLog.e("Microphone prepare() failed" + e.getMessage().toString());
            }
            mRecorder.start();
```

Comment: Don't think in terms of top and bottom. That will differ by model.  One will use the one defined for the phone, one will use the one defined for use by the videocamera.  That's all you can know.  CAMCORDER may be on the other side of the device by the camera for all you know.

Comment: When we use define is   CAMCORDER. If it is front video then It uses top microphone else it is back video then it uses bottom microphone. I read it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.

Comment: You're still thinking in the wrong terms.  The mics aren't called top and bottom because they may not be top and bottom.  There may only be one.  There may be one front one back on the top.  Or in the middle.  They use different terms because you aren't supposed to assume the location of the microphones, because your assumptions will be right on some models and wrong on others.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan, I got it. I can define two Microphone are primary & secondary mic. The problem is How do I choose one of the two mic? You can refer this link https://gadgetguideonline.com/s9/galaxy-s9-layout-and-layout-of-galaxy-s9/galaxy_s9_layout_2_back_s9/. If I want use use both them. How do I do?

Comment: You set the audio source when you set up the media player to either be CAMCORDER or MIC, whichever you prefer.

Comment: It means CAMCORDER & MIC is same? And System controls selection of Microphone?

Comment: THey can be, but they might not be.  You would call recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); or recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);  when setting up the recorder to choose (if there is a choice)

Comment: _"If I want use use both them. How do I do?"_ If you want to record from both mics at the same time, set up your MediaRecorder to record in stereo.

Comment: Have you found any solution to choose as a specific microphone(e.g Top or bottom) for audio source?

Answer (score -1):

This is my code

```
                mFileName = FunctionIndex.PATH + "/" + this.functionKey +".3gp";
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    MyLog.e("Microphone prepare() failed" + e.getMessage().toString());
                }
                mRecorder.start();
```

And What different of MIC & CAMCORDER ?

Comment: Don't post updates to your question as an answer. Edit your question instead.